# Applications of Data Mining in economics

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, application

I am looking for a thesis topic for my Applied Economics degree where I can use Data Mining/Machine Learning for some kind of prediction.

Do you guys have any good ideas about what I could do?

My first thought was credit scoring, but that seems a little boring considering the number of papers out there and the lack of available data.

I don't want to write about stock market forecasting because that's what I did for my mathematician thesis.

A good topic would be predicting some sort of an economical indicator but I don't really have any good ideas so far.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried asking a professor in your department for ideas?

Comment: The economics department is not very big on data mining, I asked them but they couldnt give me any good ideas

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about getting a thesis topic rather than a statistical question itself

Answer (score 5):

Here's a [nice survey](http://www.stanford.edu/~jdlevin/Papers/BigData.pdf) by Einav and Levin of what's been done and some directions for further research (Section 5). Here is an application to [Netflix data and price discrimination](http://www.benjaminshiller.com/images/First_Degree_PD_and_Big_Data.pdf) where ML techniques do the heavy lifting in feature selection and demand estimation. Here's [a paper on Yelp review fraud](http://people.hbs.edu/mluca/FakeItTillYouMakeIt.pdf), where Yelp's fraud detection algorithm provided identification. This is a more gingerly use of these methods.

Here's another [nice survey](http://pubs.aeaweb.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1257/jep.28.2.3) by [Hal Varian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hal_Varian) (chief economist at Google).

Comment: How are you doing ?Send me an email to catch up.

Comment: the first link of the "nice survey" doesn't work.

Comment: @AlexTwain Link is fixed.

Comment: I'm curious, is @IrishStat stalking you or something? Who is he?! :p

Comment: Dimitriy and I worked together on his Domino's data when he was at Domino's. They were interested in using AUTOBOX to predict activity at 15 minute intervals. Give me a call if you wish to discuss this offline.

Answer (score 2):

There's a recent article that uses Google Trends to predict financial crises or other economic events:
http://www.nature.com/srep/2013/130425/srep01684/full/srep01684.html

A similar approach can use Twitter (as in [here](http://www.technologyreview.com/view/421201/how-to-use-twitter-for-personal-data-mining/)), to predict other economic events or variables (e.g. marginal utilities, prices, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Hidden Markov models (HMMs) in the form of "regime switching models" have been used to determine growth/decline periods (I know, they're not *technically* HMMs, but they basically are). Does that count? Read up on the work of James Hamilton if you're interested: http://weber.ucsd.edu/~jhamilto/